# Consulta MYSQL, ultimo registro de una tabla

Tags: mysql

tengo las siguientes dos tablas 
`User (Email(PK), Nombre, Rol)` y `Message (Id (Pk), IDSend (FK), IDDest(FK), Mensaje, Status, Fecha)`

Requiero retornar el Email, el Nombre, el mensaje y el Status del último mensaje de cada usuario registrado en la base de datos. ¿Alguna idea que puedan darme?

Esto es lo que llevo

```
Select IDSend, MAX(Fecha) as Date, Status, Mensaje 
FROM message group by IDSend HAVING IDSend in (Select Email from user)
```

Comment: claro que se te puede apoyar pero sería ideal si muestras que avance llevas

Comment: Lo he intentando de muchas formas, la más reciente está: Select IDSend, MAX(Fecha) as Date, Status, Mensaje FROM message group by IDSend  HAVING IDSend in (Select Email from user) 

Me está retornando todos los usuarios registrados y la fecha correcta pero no el mensaje y el status correcto.

Comment: la `Email(PK)` de Users con que Foreign Key de Message se vincula?

Comment: @shadow con IDSent de la tabla message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer esto en SQL standard, hariamos lo siguiente:

Recuperamos el ultimo mensaje de cada usuario

```
Select IDSend, Max(Fecha)
From Message 
Group by IDSend
```

Ahora, usamos ese query como entrada de otro query, para poder obtener los valores de cada una de las otras tablas

```
Select U.Email, U.Nombre, M.Mensaje, M.Status
From (
    Select IDSend, Max(Fecha)
    From Message 
    Group by IDSend) as A
inner join User as U on U.Email = A.IDSend 
inner join Message as M on M.Fecha = A.Fecha
```

Lo que hacemos en este ultimo query, es una vez obtenidos los IDSend que queriamos, los volvemos a cruzar con las tablas que tienen los campos que queriamos.

Como la tabla A tiene un solo registro por usuario y es el que tiene la maxima fecha, solo va a traer esos datos.

Hay otra forma de hacer esto, y es haciendo subquerys directamente en el select. El resultado termina siendo el mismo, pero la sintaxis se ve mas compleja.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción puede ser la siguiente

```
SELECT User.Email, User.Nombre,
    Message.Mensaje, Message.Status
FROM User
JOIN Message ON User.Email = Message.IDSend
GROUP BY User.Nombre
ORDER BY('Message.Id', 'DESC')
```

> Lo que hice en el aterior ejemplo fue primero listar todas las
>   columnas que deseo recuperar, posterior hago un `JOIN` con la tabla
>   `Message` después de eso hago un `GROUP BY` para que si encuentra
>   coincidencias de mas un mensaje del mismo usuario los junte todos por
>   `Ùser.Nombre` finalmente como deseo obtener el mas reciente de cada
>   usuario, hag un `ORDER BY()` usando la columna Id de la tabla Message,
>   ya que `Id` es PK y auto incremental por lo cual me estaría
>   recuperando el último registro creado

Comment: Pero esto no devuelve todos los mensajes? como sabe cual es el ultimo? y si agrupas por un solo campo que hace con el resto?

Comment: @gbianchi lo propuse para obtener el ultimo mensaje de cada usuario, al menos así lo entendí en la pregunta; como se pudiera dar el caso de que un usuario tenga mas de un mensaje, por eso agrupe y ordeno de manera desc para que muestre el último (pero repito al menos asi fue como lo entendí)

Comment: pero por mas que ordenes, va a traer todos.. lo unico que va a dejar como primero el ultimo.. y los otros campos, cuales trae? o sea.. capaz mysql permite hacer algo asi, que seria medio cualquier cosa y no respeta sql ansi.. pero en realidad en sql comun esto no funcionaria, ya que no podes agrupar por un solo campo.. Podrias aclarar eso?

Comment: al menos para otros ejercicios, dentro de mysql si me ha sido posible agrupar por una sola columna; igual dejame revisar mejor tus observaciones para comprender lo que me expones @gbianchi

Comment: Voy a escribir una respuesta en sql comun. pero revisa esta por favor.

Comment: entendido gracias por las observaciones