# Como puedo generar un numero de serie para un sistema de venta

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas gente estuve buscando como poder realizar un numero de serie de forma ascendente como el id en base de datos pero no he podido encontrar nada especifico ya que necesito este numero para realizar consultas en la erp de sap para poder realizar editar y eliminar, lo estuve haciendo con random para generar numero aleatorios pero necesito que sea de forma ascendente.
Actualmente lo inserto de forma manual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el sistema de SAP en el cual el numero de orden esta a la derecha en la parte superior en cual ya va en numero 14 ese dato necesito crear como numero de pedido en mi sistema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya que no veo ningún código al respecto, te daré una idea: podrías hacer una consulta en tu sql que te retorne el [último id](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218344/consulta-mysql-ultimo-registro-de-una-tabla) de la tabla, ese resultado le sumas 1 y lo almacenas en una variable para llamarlo en la vista, así funcionaría el correlativo de forma ascendente.

Comment: Y en tu base de datos ese número (que supongo es la ID) no es auto incrementable??? y si no lo es, lo puedes poner a auto incrementable?

Comment: si no es un **pk**, sería un problema :)...

Comment: lo quiero hacer en base al id del pedido, no he podido encontrar algo relacionado ya que este numero debe ser igual al numero de orden en sap

Comment: Pero el número de orden en SAP ya existe???

Comment: no cuando yo creo el pedido y es enviado sin importar en numero de serie que yo cree la orden en sap se crea automaticamente con los datos que envio pero ese dato necesito usarlo para editar en sap

Comment: es como tener un id para poder usarlo con sap

Comment: No logro entender del todo la situación. Son 2 bases de datos?? Si ese ID se crea automáticamente, quien los debería crear???  Usas Entity Framework?

Comment: no bro no son 2 bases de datos SAP Businness one es un ERP que gestiona toda la parte administrativa de una empresa, como tambien ventas e inventario la parte que me pidieron desarrollar es crear los pedidos cuando este se crea el sistema crea un numero de orden con los datos del socio de negocio y los productos

Comment: Edite la pregunta para que sea mas entendible, pero en resumen se como armar el json para obtener sus datos pero necesito obtener el numero de orden, y es lo que no tengo en mi sistema